# ignore_sticky_posts in WordPress 3.0.3?

Tags: sticky-post

I am using WP 3.0.3 and I would like to exclude sticky posts from my query:

This doesn't seem to work:

```
<?php query_posts( 'posts_per_page=9&cat=-1,-2&ignore_sticky_posts=1' );?>
```

To get JUST the sticky post I use the following:

```
$sticky = get_option('sticky_posts');
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post__in'  => $sticky
);
query_posts($args);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ignore_sticky_posts` was introduced in WordPress 3.1. Before this version, you can use `caller_get_posts`, which will have the same effect (this option was used when you queried the posts via `get_posts()`, which uses the same `WP_Query` class in the background, but should ignore sticky posts). The name was a bit confusing, and thus [changed in 3.1](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14624).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using

```
query_posts( array( 'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

`'post__in'` will be changed to `'post__not_in'` in your code. Thanks!